# ¿que significa *s en el codigo?

Tags: c

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
No entendo a que se refiere, mientras que s no sea nulo /0

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, para que la gente pueda ayudarte mejor, por favor, pega el código en vez de una imágen. Así será más fácil copiar y pegar para ejecutarlo. De paso, hazte el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y obtienes tu primera medalla y aprendes a como preguntar. Puedes [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/365359/edit) tu pregunta y a la derecha tienes una guía de como usar Markdown. Un saludo.

Comment: Esta sentencia: `while(*s)` es equivalente a: `while(*s != 0)`. Simplemente es una forma corta de escribir la *condición*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El * en una variable significa que es un puntero. Un puntero no es más que una variable cuyo contenido es una dirección de memoria.

Un puntero, en C, se declara como sigue:

```
TIPO * nombre_puntero ;
```

Donde TIPO es cualquier tipo definido. Así, un puntero a carácter se declararia de la siguiente forma:

```
char *pchar;
```

Un ejemplo práctico es:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

int a = 0; //Declaración de variable entera de tipo entero
int *puntero; //Declaración de variable puntero de tipo entero
puntero = &a; //Asignación de la dirección memoria de a

printf("El valor de a es: %d. \nEl valor de *puntero es: %d. \n",a,*puntero);
printf("La dirección de memoria de *puntero es: %p",puntero);

return 0;
}
```

Te dejo un [enlace](https://programacion.net/articulo/5_libros_gratuitos_para_aprender_a_programar_en_c_y_c++_1076) con algunos libros gratuitos. Saludos amigo.

Comment: *Un puntero no es más que una variable estática...* No es del todo cierto, eso depende si en la declaración le antepones el `static` o no..

Answer (score 0):

`s` es el nombre de la variable, y el `*` que le precede indica que `s` no es una variable corriente, sino un apuntador o puntero. En C, las cadenas de caracteres se almacenan en memoria como arrays, ocupando cada caracter de la cadena una posición en la lista y finalizando con el caracter especial '\0'. Este caracter no es visible y su única función es la de marcar el final de la cadena.

Además, este caracter en su representación ASCII, tiene valor 0. Esto es importante puesto que en C no existen valores booleanos y todo lo que es 0 o nulo se evalúa a falso, y todo lo demás a verdadero.

Sabiendo esto, se puede explicar de forma sencilla que es lo que hace la función `cuentaVocales`:

Recibe como entrada `char *s`, esto es, una variable llamada `s` de tipo `char *`, o lo que es lo mismo un puntero a un caracter o una cadena de caracteres.

Comprueba que el valor de la dirección de memoria a la que apunta el puntero no sea nula. Si es nula, se evalúa a falso y se salde del bucle. Si no lo es, se evalúa a verdadero y ejecuta lo que se encuentra dentro del bucle (se comprueba `*s` y no `s` porque `s` contiene la dirección de memoria donde se está almacenando el caracter)

```
// Si *s es nulo se evalúa a falso y no se ejecuta el contenido del bucle
// Si *s no es nulo, se evalúa a verdadero y se ejecuta el contenido del bucle
while (*s) {
   // ...
}
```

Después, se incrementa el contador si la letra es una vocal

```
switch (*s) {
   case 'a':
   case 'e':
   case 'i':
   case 'o':
   case 'u': cont++; // Si el valor de *s es 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o' o 'u' incrementa el contador de vocales
}
```

Finalmente, avanza a la siguiente dirección de memoria (la siguiente posición del array)

```
s++; // Avanza a la siguiente posición de memoria
```